# Android ViewPager/ListView weird display bug

Tags: android, listview, android-viewpager

I have created a small app, which parses an html document and displays it in a ListView contained in a `ViewPager`. So far so good, everything is working fine - at least on *my* phone.

Now I have asked some people to try and test the app for me as well, and for the most it seems to be working as well as for me. Some people however (only Samsung-Phone users by the way) have the following problem:

#### What it *should* look like:

[image: What it should look like]
[image: With layout borders]

#### What it *does* look like for some people:

[image: What it does look like]
[image: With layout borders]

(Blurred out content for privacy reasons)

I have borrowed a phone from one of these people and conencted it to my laptop so I could check the logs. Since all try/catch clauses should print out the exception and there was nothing in the logs, I have tried altering the XML file a little, without success.

#### My code:

**Activity with ViewPager:**

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout     xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/main_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context="de.fuchstim.vertretungsplan.Table">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/appbar_padding_top"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay">

        </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"/>


    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|right"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/reload_arrow_white" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

**ViewPager Fragment:**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <TextView
        android:text="Heute (25.10.16)"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/title"
    android:textAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.DeviceDefault.DialogWindowTitle"
        android:textAlignment="center" />

    <GridLayout android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/grade_desc"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Klasse"
            android:layout_row="0"
            android:layout_column="0"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:textSize="14sp"
            android:layout_columnWeight="30"
            android:paddingStart="10dp" />

        <TextView
            android:text="Stunde"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/hour_desc"
            android:layout_row="0"
            android:layout_column="1"
            android:layout_columnWeight="17.5"/>

        <TextView
            android:text="Lehrer"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/teacher_desc"
            android:layout_row="0"
            android:layout_column="3"
            android:layout_columnWeight="17.5"/>

        <TextView
            android:text="Kurs"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/course_desc"
            android:layout_row="0"
            android:layout_column="2"
            android:layout_columnWeight="17.5"/>

        <TextView
            android:text="Raum"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/room_desc"
            android:layout_row="0"
            android:layout_column="4"
            android:layout_columnWeight="17.5"/>

    </GridLayout>

    <ListView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:id="@+id/listView" />

</LinearLayout>
```

**ListView Item:**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<GridLayout android:layout_gravity="left"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingTop="10dp">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/grade"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Klasse"
        android:layout_row="0"
        android:layout_column="0"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        android:layout_columnWeight="30"
        android:paddingStart="10dp" />

    <TextView
        android:text="Stunde"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/hour"
        android:layout_row="0"
        android:layout_column="1"
        android:layout_columnWeight="17.5"/>

    <TextView
        android:text="Lehrer"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/teacher"
        android:layout_row="0"
        android:layout_column="3"
        android:layout_columnWeight="17.5"/>

    <TextView
        android:text="Kurs"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/course"
        android:layout_row="0"
        android:layout_column="2"
        android:layout_columnWeight="17.5"/>

    <TextView
        android:text="Raum"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/room"
        android:layout_row="0"
        android:layout_column="4"
        android:layout_columnWeight="17.5"/>

</GridLayout>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/description"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:ellipsize="marquee"
    android:maxLines="1"
    android:text="Description"
    android:textSize="12sp"
    android:layout_row="1"
    android:layout_column="0"
    android:gravity="left"
    android:paddingTop="5dp"
    android:paddingStart="10dp"
    android:paddingBottom="5dp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

---

```
public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
    public SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        if(position==0)
            return TodayTableFragment.newInstance(position + 1);
        if(position==1)
            return  TmrwTableFragment.newInstance(position + 1);
        else
            return TodayTableFragment.newInstance(position + 1);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return 2;
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                return "today";
            case 1:
                return "tomorrow";
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

---

```
public static class TodayTableFragment extends Fragment {
    private static final String ARG_SECTION_NUMBER = "section number";

    public TodayTableFragment() {
    }
    public static TodayTableFragment newInstance(int sectionNumber) {
        TodayTableFragment fragment = new TodayTableFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER,sectionNumber);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater,ViewGroup container,Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list,container,false);
        todayTitle = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.title);

        String[] tmp = new String[tableData[0].length+1];
        ListView listView = (ListView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.listView);
        todayListAdapter = new TodayListAdapter(getActivity(),R.layout.list_item,tmp);
        listView.setAdapter(todayListAdapter);

        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
                if(!tableData[0][i][6].isEmpty()) {
                    Snackbar.make(view, "Vertretungs-Text:\n" + tableData[0][i][6], Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                } else {
                    Snackbar.make(view,"Keine weiteren Informationen vorhanden",Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }
        });

        todayTitle.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Snackbar.make(getView(),addInfo[2],Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });
        todayTitle.setText(addInfo[0]);
        return rootView;
    }
}
```

---

```
public static class TodayListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {
    public TodayListAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId) {
        super(context,textViewResourceId);
    }
    public TodayListAdapter(Context context, int resource, String[] items) {
        super(context,resource,items);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View v = convertView;

        if(v == null) {
            LayoutInflater vi;
            vi = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());
            v = vi.inflate(R.layout.list_item, null);
        }

        String p = getItem(position);

        if(p==null) {
            TextView grade = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.grade);
            TextView hour = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.hour);
            TextView course = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.course);
            TextView teacher = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.teacher);
            TextView room = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.room);
            TextView description = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.description);

            try {
                grade.setText(tableData[0][position][0]);
                hour.setText(tableData[0][position][1]);
                course.setText(tableData[0][position][2]);
                teacher.setText(tableData[0][position][3]);
                room.setText(tableData[0][position][4]);
                description.setText(tableData[0][position][5]);
            } catch (ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                return v;
            }
        }

        return v;
    }
}
```

Has anyone ever had similar problems? How did you fix it? Or have I made a mistake somewhere?

Thanks in advance ^.^

## EDIT I:

### Update

I have found out that if I remove the columnWeight option and set the width to a fixed size, it works fine. How do I achieve that without removing the columnWeight option?

## EDIT II:

### Update

I have changed the GridLayout to LinearLayout, it appears to be working now

Answer (score 0):

In `getItem()` you return `TodayTableFragment.newInstance(position + 1)` twice.you can not do like this.Also at `getCount` method you return 2.In your case it should be 3.

Comment: Okay, I have changed the getItem() Method. I do not quite understand why getCount() must return three? Doesn't it set the total amount of pages in the ViewPager?

Comment: yes.it should be count with `else` return page.if you write like this
`public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        if(position==0)
            return TodayTableFragment.newInstance(position + 1);
       else
            return  TmrwTableFragment.newInstance(position + 1); }` 
then count value will be 2

Comment: I have changed the if/else statement to if(position==0){return TodayTable[...]} else {return TmrwTable[...]}